# Creating a listener onRotate()

Tags: android, listener, rotation, dimensions, seekbar

I've been trying to find a listener that can execute seekmark.markPlace(). The function takes in the dimensions and padding for a seekBar defined in my layout. When I call the function from onCreate it returns 0 for the values of the seekBar. I need a listener that can call the function outside of onCreate. The function should only run if the screen is rotated (when layout-land is created).

```
    public class seekMark {
    private int seekLength;     // in pixels 
    private int seekLeftPad;    // in pixels
    private int seekBottomPad;  // in pixels
    private int trackLength;    // in ms

    public seekMark(){
        seekLength = progressBar.getWidth();
        seekLeftPad = progressBar.getPaddingLeft();
        seekBottomPad = progressBar.getPaddingBottom();
        trackLength = player.getDuration();
    }

    private int pxPerMs(){
        return (seekLength/trackLength);
    }

    public void markPlace() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Drawable marker = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio);
        int y = seekBottomPad;
        int x = 0;
        int w = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int[] bmPos = markPxList(); // returns a list of px (from the left) read from a xml database

        for(int i = 0; i <= bmPos.length; i++){
            x = bmPos[i] + seekLeftPad;
            marker.setBounds( x, y, x + w, y + h );
            marker.draw( canvas );
        }

    }

}
```

Is it possible to make your own listener like onRotate() or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since onCreate is going to be called when the device is rotated anyways, why not just use a private variable to store the orientation of the display. Each time onCreate() is called, you can compare to see if the display orientation is changed:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();

if(rotation != mPreviousRotation) {
    mPreviousRotation = rotation;

    // Insert code for handling rotation here
}
```

I'll leave it to you to decide how to handle initialization of the mPreviousRotation variable during the first invocation of onCreate().

Comment: I've tried that. The problem is onCreate is where I make the progressBar. So, it doesn't exist yet, and the values for seekLength, seekLeftPad, and seekBottomPad are zero.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you would explain what it is you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to set the seek mark position to match it's position before the rotation?

Comment: I'm trying to place images onto a progress bar. Right now, I'm testing the seekmark.markPlace() function by running it when ever a button is pushed. I ran into a problem with "Drawable marker = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio);" the program crashes whenever it runs it.